# REgex to get numeric from string in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have strings in the following formats

Akram_88_jamesstree_20140418,
Akram_8_johnstreet_20140418,
Akram_888_johnstreet_20140418,

Now I want to retrieve only the 88,8 and 888 value only, for which i have written the following query

`SUBSTR(a.file_name, 7, INSTR(a.file_name, '_')-5) as output`

now the problem with this query is i just get 88 -8 and 88 of 888.

The output will be compared to another column so i want just 88,8 and 888 numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Akram_88_jamesstree','[0-9]+')
```

Here put your column Name in place of 'Akram_88_jamesstree'.

Comment: i get only 0 or 1 as output

Comment: 'Akram_88_jamesstree' is a file name with an extension of .txt

Comment: @akram The expression is valid. Can you show your full query?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov the file name is something like this Akram_88_jamesstree_20140418.TXT, so when I run this query it will not work.

Comment: @akram Let's start with simple things. Does `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Akram_88_jamesstree_20140418.TXT','[0-9]+') FROM DUAL;` work for you?

Comment: @akram What is the version of Oracle you have? And what does the query return?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov i have 10g with me when i run that query i get 0 or 1 .